What's with this /u symlink that points to /Users?
There's a symlink in my root directory called u. It points to Users. It looks like it's being created at boot time, but idk if that means anything. I don't remember this being part of a normal macOS install. I don't have access to any other macOS systems, so I can't compare.
I'm running Ventura 13.6.6 (22G630) on a 16-inch, 2019 MBP. Last clean install was Monterey 12.0.1 in October 2021.
❯ ls -l /u
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  5 Apr 12 15:10 /u -> Users

❯ GetFileInfo -P /u
file: "/u"
type: "slnk"
creator: "rhap"
attributes: Avbstclinmedz
created: 04/12/2024 15:10:07
modified: 04/12/2024 15:10:07

❯ who -b
         system boot  2024-04-12 15:10


I don't have macOS 13 anymore, but /u does not exist on my macOS 14 and I have never seen it before. Is there an entry in /etc/synthetic.conf ?

@MartinR Okay, thanks, for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out, I myself added it several years ago and forget all about it.

Feeling kinda foolish, but here it is: No, this is not a standard macOS thing, nor is it something that an application added. I added it myself several years ago and promptly forgot about it. Here's the contents of my /etc/synthetic.conf:
#sam# For dotfile portability between macOS and Linux.
u       Users


You can accept your own answer to make it clear it's been answered
